# Where in the VB6/VBA project references do Array(), LBound(), and UBound() come from..?

Tags: vba, vb6

Where in the VB6/VBA project references do Array(), LBound(), and UBound() come from..? When I'm typing in code, they don't appear in the Autocomplete list (ctrl+space), they don't get autocompleted, and they must be typed out completely before the text editor recognizes them. And only when a left-parenthesis is typed will ToolTipText pop up with the command syntax. Also, they do not appear anywhere in Object Explorer.

There's probably a basic concept in play here that I'm not aware of. And it makes me wonder, what other commands/statements/keywords are hidden in the same way..? Is there a list somewhere..? I googled for info but didn't find anything, probably because I don't know what I'm looking for and using the wrong search terms.

I ask these questions because I have the habit of prefixing many VB6 built-in functions like this: VBA.Left(), VBA.Len, VBA.Instr(), and so on. But I can't figure out what reference prefeix to use with Array(), LBound(), and UBound(), or perhaps they're so basic to VB6 that they don't have one.

I do this prefixing because years ago I was working on a large project, and there were functions I was trying to use with the same name in different reference libraries. I was a newbie and it took me a while to figure out, and it was causing tremendous problems since the functions were just NOT working the way I thought they were supposed to. It was then that I developed the prefixing habit after I figured it out. It's just easier that way, and always ensures the expected functions are being used.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sh9ywfdk.aspx

Comment: @KenWhite - That's the VB.NET reference. - `Array`, `LBound`, and `UBound` actually *are* in the VB namespace in that language.

Comment: @Comintern: Perhaps you're reading a different question than I am. ** Is there a list somewhere..?** is pretty clear to me. Is there a particular reason for the snark?

Comment: @KenWhite - Fair enough, but I was judging by the title and first sentence that this wasn't a question about "where do I find the documentation for VBA".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that they don't appear as IntelliSense options (and also why they don't appear in the Object Browser) is that they aren't declared in the VBE7.dll typelib for some reason that's beyond me.  The `Array` function is implemented in the .dll as `rtcArray`.  The utility of knowing that is dubious, in that its sole argument is a `ParamArray`, which means that if you called it directly from VBE7.dll you would need to create an array to have it feed you back the same array... This partially explains why it isn't on the typelib - a COM call would need to do the same thing, and the marshaling would basically be doing the same thing as what you'd expect the function to return.

`LBound` and `UBound` don't even appear as functions in the export table, so my guess is that they are handled more like "keywords" than first class functions internally.  This makes *some* sense, in that it's fairly trivial to check the bounds of a [SAFEARRAY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221482(v=vs.85).aspx) if you have a pointer to the automation struct (you just index into the `rgsabound` array at the end of it and read the `cElements` and `lLbound` from it. Again a guess, but I'd assume that this allows for flexibility in letting `LBound` and `UBound` function with both fixed length and variable length arrays.  In the fixed case, the array is basically managed as a block of memory with an indexer (more like a `VT_CARRAY` than a `VT_SAFEARRAY`).  I'd imagine that handling this internally was easier or more convenient than providing first-class functions.

Comment: Thank you, that irons it out for me. I've dabbled with TLBINF32.DLL, so I understand what you're saying. But in the second paragraph, you take a trip into C-land and I get lost there. I recently took four semesters of Java in college and discovered an interesting side effect that I wasn't expecting: now I can read C++ code and almost understand it.

Comment: @spinjector - The takeaway there is that LBound and UBound have to deal with 2 very different types of arrays - fixed ones (which aren't wrapped for COM usage with a safearray) and variable ones (which are the safearray structs).  So with a variable one, you just read the struct. For a fixed one, you have to know the details of how you allocated memory for it, the type, etc. Typically unwrapped arrays are passed with parameters describing the element size and the array length.  That means there isn't really a safe way to expose a function that can handle them on a public interface.

Comment: Weird, off the top it seems like it would be the other way around, with the dynamic array being more difficult.

Comment: @spinjector - A C style array is just a block of memory.  When they get passed around you typically pass the upper bound and element size with it.  The SAFEARRAY wrapper is a structured way of passing that information in a single pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You `won't` find `Debug` in the Object Browser either, nor its methods `Assert` and `Print`.

You won't find **Statements** that are used like methods, like `Open`, `Close`, `Get` and `Put`, which is why you don't get any Intellisense when you use those statements, and the syntax must be memorized.

You *will* find `Load` and `Unload` as members of `VBA.Global`, but it's not clear what they belong to otherwise, and their arguments are late-bound `Objects`. The VBA documentation states that `Load` and `Unload` are **Statements**, even though the Object Browser shows them as **Methods**.

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind that you can move the order of references and it will make a difference.  Try moving VBA to the top or near the top of your list of references.  I believe that if something else also defines a BASIC keyword, it steals it, in a sense.  I once had Right disappear and because I was not aware of the order of references, had to change all references of Right to VBA.Right.  It's possibly the same with the ubound, lbound, or array.

Comment: "it steals it" - the correct term is "hides", as in "member hiding". The VBA Standard Library [**cannot be moved**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lsf4.png) however - it's hard-wired to be the top-priority. Same with the host application's object model library...

Comment: Maybe try your suggestions in the VBE first? `UBound`, `LBound` and `Array` are all reserved words, so you can't create procedures with those names. It's not clear what would happen if you had identifiers with those names in a referenced TLB, but in any case, the VBA project is **fixed** at position 1 in the references of **all** VBA Projects, so you assertion about moving references is flawed.

Comment: Ahhh, I'm wondering now if I'm remembering it backwards, and in fact had to prefix the functions with the other library identifier. If memory serves, I was working in a project with DAO as one of the references, and I wanted the one from DAO rather than from VBA. I think I was trying to use a string function such as .Compare or .Len and it was reacting very differently than the documentations described.